# scaling an image on a CALayer?

Tags: ios, dictionary, calayer

I have a map, on which are placed markers that inherit from CALayer.
I would like to scale the images on this layers, but keep their anchor point.
Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the layers will scale relative to their anchor point property without changing it.

Comment: If you have set a custom anchor point (or are fine with center as the default) and apply a scale transform (`myLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1.0);`) then the layer will automatically scale in relation to the anchor point

Comment: Also found setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5); Thanks!